# How to filter out list items of two huge lists?

Tags: python, performance

I have a *huge* list, which is `all_entries` (currently 80k integer items). In this list contains items I already handled in my overall program.

When my program uses the following method, it usually takes around 30s to get to the return statement. How can I speed this up?

Tip: `new_entries` is 40k long, so huge as well.

```
def get_fresh_entries(self, new_entries, all_entries):
    """
    :param new_entries: Entries from which some might already be in all_entries.
    :param all_entries: Entries already handled and saved.
    """
    fresh = []
    shuffle(new_entries)

    for i in new_entries:
        if i not in all_entries:
            fresh.append(i)
        if len(fresh) > 80000:
            break
    return fresh
```

Comment: 40k and 80k is not _huge_

Comment: `[x for x in new_entries if x not in all_entries]` does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **only** problem is the line `if i not in all_entries:` which is executed for every new entry and tests against up to 80k existing entries.

Here it is important to understand the difference when performig the test on a list or on a set.

- testing if an element is in a list is like testing if someone is at home without knowing the address (just the town) and go from door to door.
- testing if an element is in a set is like testing if someone is at home, knowing the exact address and ring a single doorbell

So simply converting `all_entries` to a set once(!) will eliminate the primary speed issue.

```
...
all_entries_set = set(all_entries)
for i in new_entries:
    if i not in all_entries_set:
        ...
```

While there are other hints how to speedup your program using a set is the crucial one because it reduces complexity.

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension will do:

As **@Delgan** comment, is better if all_entries is a set.

```
all_entries = set(all_entries)
```

Then:

```
fresh = [x for x in new_entries if x not in all_entries]
```

Also take a look at [itertools.ifilter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter), it is [lazyly evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation):

```
fresh = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x not in all_entries, new_entries)
```

In case you need to keep only the first `n` data, since itertools is lazy you can just take them like this:

```
fresh = itertools.islice(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x not in all_entries, 
                                           new_entries),
                         n))
```

or with the list comprehension like, but using a generator instead:

```
fresh = itertools.islice((x for x in new_entries if x not in all_entries), n)
```

Comment: Also `all_entries` should be a `set()` so `x not in all_entries` is `O(1)`.

Comment: You can use generator to replace list comprehension.

Comment: Okay, that seems to work in a way, but I'd really just use a loop instead. Using a list comprehension or generator does not fix OP's problem, but only makes it more complicated than necessary. Making `all_entries` a `set` is the only significant part, and you don't even emphasize that.

Comment: @tobias_k, maybe the loop is more comprensive in a way, probably much slower also, itertools is there for this kind of operations, but that is just personal apreciations, for you and for me, go ahead and make an answer to expand this question so the so uers have a wide range of options when someone doubt about the same. Thanks!! :)

Comment: `itertools.islice((x for x in new_entries if x not in all_entries), 80000)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands, actually you are right, that is much better, i overcomplicated

Answer (score 2):

Using set operations can significantly speed up your code. I have defined a new function `get_fresh_entries_2` which uses set operations. And at the end I have added a small speed comparison. Using set operations speeds up the process by a huge factor

```
from random import shuffle
from itertools import compress
from time import time

def get_fresh_entries_2(new_entries, all_entries):
    shuffle(new_entries)
    diff = set(new_entries)- set(all_entries)
    if len(new_entries) > 80000:
        ind = [i in diff for i in new_entries[:80000]] 
    else:
        ind = [i in diff for i in new_entries] 
    fresh = compress(new_entries,ind)
    return list(fresh)


def get_fresh_entries(new_entries, all_entries):
    """
    :param new_entries: Entries from which some might already be in all_entries.
    :param all_entries: Entries already handled and saved.
    """
    fresh = []
    shuffle(new_entries)

    for i in new_entries:
        if i not in all_entries:
            fresh.append(i)
        if len(fresh) > 80000:
            break
    return fresh

new_entries = np.asarray(np.random.randint(1,11, size = (40000))).tolist()
all_entries = np.asarray(np.random.randint(0,10, size = (80000))).tolist()
t0 = time()
a = get_fresh_entries(new_entries, all_entries)
t1 = time()
b = get_fresh_entries_2(new_entries, all_entries)
t2 = time()

t1-t0 # 4.321316957473755 sec
t2-t1 # 0.005052804946899414 sec
```

Comment: @Saphire, if you get rid of the `shuffle(new_entries)` step, the implementation becomes even faster (by an order of 9-10)

Comment: `True if condition else False` is the same as just `condition`. Also, why turn `diff` into a `list`? That will only make the lookup slower.

Comment: @tobias_k, edited the answer. The operation does speed up

Comment: `[True if i in diff for i in new_entries[:80000]]` is syntactically wrong; it should be just `[i in diff for i in new_entries[:80000]]`. Also, you can use this for both cases, regardless of whether the list has more than 80k entries or not. Also, the functions are not equivalent. Limiting to 80k before filtering will give you fewer than 80k in the result.